# What's the best Mongo index strategy that includes a date range

Tags: mongodb

I have the following schema:

```
{
  a: string;
  b: date;
  c: number;
}
```

My query is

```
find({
  a: 'some value',
  b: {
    $gte: new Date('some date')
  }
})
.sort({ 
 c: -1
});
```

I have an index that is:

```
{ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 }
```

But it's not using this index.

I have several other indexes, and when analyzing my explain(), it shows it's employing multiple other indexes to accomplish my query.

I believe since my "b" query is a date range, that's not considered an equality condition, so maybe that index won't work?

Should I have two indexes:
{ a: 1, c: 1} and separately { b: 1 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates tend to be much more selective than other fields, so when you have an index that looks like `{dateField: 1, otherField: 1}`, the selectivity of the `dateField` means that `otherField` will be useless unless you have multiple items that share the same date.

Depending on what your data distribution actually looks like, you might consider `{otherField: 1, dateField: 1}` (which means that mongo can go through in sorted order to check whether the docs match your date query). In general, putting your sort field *before* any fields used in a range query is a good idea.

[Mlab's indexing docs](https://docs.mlab.com/indexing/#sorting-efficiently) are the best resource I've seen on index usage, and they recommend:

> A good rule of thumb for queries with sort is to order the indexed fields in this order:
>
> - First, the field(s) on which you will query for exact values
> - Second, one small $in array
> - Third, the field(s) on which you will sort in the same order and specification as the sort itself (sorting on multiple fields)
> - Finally, the field(s) on which you will query for a range of values in the order of most selective to least selective (see range operators below)

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful